# Why are compact arithmetic surfaces defined through quaternion algebras (usually) only over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, modular-forms, hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

As in Chapter 6.2 of "Introduction to arithmetic groups" (by D.W. Morris), compact arithmetic surfaces could be defined through quaternion algebras $\mathbb{H}^{a,b}_F=\big(\frac{a,b}{F}\big)$ (for example $a=b=\sqrt{2},F=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$), while in many papers, compact arithmetic surfaces are restricted to the case $a,b\in\mathbb{Z},F=\mathbb{Q}$.

Hecke operators always play important roles: for $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, put $R(m)=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{H}^{a,b}_\mathbb{Z}\mid \alpha\overline{\alpha}=m\}$, then $R(1)\backslash R(m)$ is finite. Since $R(m)$ acts naturally on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$, we have the Hecke operator $T_m\colon L^2(R(1)\backslash\mathbb{H})\to L^2(R(1)\backslash\mathbb{H})$ given by
\begin{equation}
T_mf(z)=\sum_{\alpha\in R(1)\backslash R(m)}f(\alpha z).
\end{equation}
Could we define Hecke operators analogously by replacing $\mathbb{H}^{a,b}_\mathbb{Z},m\in\mathbb{N}^+,R(m)$ with $\mathbb{H}^{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}}_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]},m\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^+,R(m)=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{H}^{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}}_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]}\mid \alpha\overline{\alpha}=m\}$ respectively?

Comment: I think one often restricts to the $F \in \mathbb Q$ case for simplicity.

Comment: @WillSawin, thanks for your comment! I've added some details, it would be greatly appreciated if you could take a look.

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the body are quite different.  What do you want to know?  How to define Hecke operators?

Comment: @Kimball, sorry I didn't explain it clearly, I was wondering if one usually restricts to $F=\mathbb{Q}$ just because we cannot define the Hecke operators on cases like $R(1)=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{H}^{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}}_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]}\mid \alpha\overline{\alpha}=1\}$?

Comment: @Local Hecke operators are (always) defined for any arithmetic lattice as sum over the double $\Gamma$ cosets. One can formulate it in adelic fashion as well.

Comment: @Asaf, thanks, while I do not know if the index finite condition is verified or not. Equivalently, is $R(1)\backslash R(m)$ a finite set for $m\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^+,R(m)=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{H}^{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}}_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]}\mid \alpha\overline{\alpha}=m\}$?

Comment: The definition is as follows - after proper modification one may identify the lattice as $\Gamma=G(\mathbb{Z})$ for appropriate alg grp $G$. For any $a\in G(\mathbb{Q})$ and $x\in \Gamma \backslash G$ one defines $T_{a}x=\{[\Gamma a \Gamma x] \}$, and the Hecke operator related to $a$ is defined as a normalized sum over the Hecke neighbors $T_{a}x$. Since $\Gamma$ and $a^{-1}\Gamma a$ are commensurable lattices, the set of Hecke neighbors is finite (and its cardinality is independent of $x$). If you are interested in the adelic formulation, I recommend looking at the Clozel-Oh-Ullmo  paper.

Comment: @Asaf, thank you very much for your detailed explanation!